ament_cmake_vendor_package, does it exist?
when trying to build the rosbag2 repo from source (following this), I encounter the following cmake error when running colcon build (yes, I have sourced setup.bash):
--- stderr: zstd_vendor                                                                                                                                              
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findament_cmake_vendor_package.cmake" in
  CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package
  configuration file provided by "ament_cmake_vendor_package", but CMake did
  not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "ament_cmake_vendor_package" with any of the following names:

    ament_cmake_vendor_packageConfig.cmake
    ament_cmake_vendor_package-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake_vendor_package" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ament_cmake_vendor_package_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "ament_cmake_vendor_package"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


In fact, zstd_vendor requires ament_cmake_vendor_package, and I see that ament_cmake_vendor_package is present in the ament_cmake repo, but I don't have ament_cmake_vendor_package and cannot install it.
I tried installing rosbag2 from source with and without a ros2 version already installed, and using jazzy or rolling distro for both rosbag2 and ros2, trying also with docker images (osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop, osrf/ros:rolling-desktop), but I always encounter the same error.
What might be my problem?

I haven't build ros2bag from source myself but what you can try using rosdep to make sure that all the dependencies are met before building it with colcon.
so in the workspace folder (not src, so where you would normally run colcon), run rosdep:
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ROSDISTRO -y

Replace ROSDISTRO with yours (humble or jazzy)
After that source the ROS setup.bash again and try colcon build.
Hope this will work for you!
